# Qucs voltage divider tutorial: simulation error

Tags: simulation, qucs, tutorial

I am going trough the voltage divider tutorial on pp. 4 and following of the [Qucs manual](https://qucs.github.io/docs/tutorial/getstarted.pdf).

[image]

On p. 11, I simulate the circuit, and I obtain following message:
[image]
What does this mean?

I cannot insert a `Tabular` on the data display page (as the simulation did not succeed).

Comment: What does your circuit look like?  Did you place a DC simulator block in the project?

Comment: It almost certainly means you did not tell Qucs to run any simulations. So it has "nothing to do". You can't insert a tabular object in the data display since if you run no simulations, you generate no data.

Comment: @JRE Yes, I did exactly as told in the tutorial. I've added the circuit to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You may click 'check DC bias' icon (it is next to simulate icon) to run your DC simulation and can get your node voltage.